# Can we write to hbase table with Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

There is lot in internet where Kstreams read data from topic , perform some transformation and write it back to a topic. But I wonder if write to hbase table is possible with KStream?. And what I mean by this is that we should read data from topic using KStream , perform some operations like we do on a dataframe and then write it to a hbase table

I didn't find any resources on internet implementing KStreams with hbase. I would be glad if anyone could help me with a piece of code in scala preferably to read from a topic or even a hbase table using KStream application , perform some transformation and write it to a hbase table

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Streams should be limited to Kafka-Kafka interactions.

There is nothing preventing you from using `.forEach` DSL or Processor API with HBase client to write elsewhere, but this is not a supported use-case. More specifically, that would be a blocking operation, whereas Kafka Streams is very time-sensitive for its actions.

You should look into using Kafka Connect API, instead. Or even Apache Spark, Flink, or NiFi as alternatives.

(This answer is not unique to HBase. RocksDB Statestores are the only database that Kafka Streams "supports" without using your own `StoreSupplier`)